# Quickly calling this.$router.replace in a row causes race condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a filter setup in my VueJs 3 app. I am using the router to update the query, like this:

```
this.$router.replace({ path: window.location.pathname, query }).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

The query is generated by the value of some computed properties. When I want to "reset" the filter, I just set all these values to their default value. This will call the router replace method for each property change. This doesn't work, as it seems like there is a race between the calls to replace. Resulting in the query not looking as it should. Here is a console log screenshot, showing how to query value is not consistent between calls to replace.

[image]